# Combined msgs into custom msgs

Tags: imu, gazebo, gps, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to combine 3 different msgs into a single one. I'd like to create a msg only with the fields required for my application and after that publish this msg into a topic. Anyone knows how can I do that?
Thanks
J.L.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194160/combined-msgs-into-custom-msgs/) by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Define [ROS custom message.](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages)

This [create and Buildt custom message tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) is helpful.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on 2014-10-03**:
I'd like to put some fields used in Imu msgs and GPS msgs in one message, like, mySensorsMsg. Did you understand? Maybe your first link will help me! Thanks!

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-03**:
yes with custom message you can create message with fields you like to have.

**Comment by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on 2014-10-03**:
Thank you very much. I'm testing it and it is working until now. If I have more doubts I will be in touch! Thankss